# How to switch bitmap texture of Object by using rajawali?

Tags: rajawali

I want to develop a function that there are has a object in my scene, and this object has a bitmap texture. Then if you touched the object, its texture will be switched to another one, how can I implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days study, I find a way which can resolve my texture replacement issue, please reference the below codes:

```
Texture texture = getTexture(TOAST_TEXTURE_NAME);
texture.setBitmap(mToastTextTexture.textAsBitmap(toastString));
TextureManager.getInstance().replaceTexture(texture);
```